# Is it possible to make a Hash MD5 in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, hash

In my form, i need to make a hash then submit it as POST.

```
<form action="{{ route('api') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Hash" value="{{  md5('2019030428' . '54321' . 'Juan dela Cruz' }}">
    <button type="submit" value="API POST">Submit</button>
</form>
```

is this correct? The instruction says i need to pass it as HASH lowercase md5

Comment: have you tried this? i assume not since you have a syntax error

Comment: this is the value i get ```2c5389963e49aef1029dbf7934a36c26``` but when i pass it to the api, it says ```Invalid Hash```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with

```php
{{strtolower(md5('STRING Is here'))}}
```